# define enum type

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I would like to create a function that contains all text and constant. From the other .m files I access to the constants with giving the name of function variable.

For example, in Java:

```
 public enum MyEnum {
    COMBO("val1"),MENU_FILE("File");}
private final String label;

  /**
   * @param label
   */
  private MyEnum(final String label)
  {
    this.label = label;
  }

   @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return this.label;
  }
}
```

Can I do the same with MATLAB?

Can I have a file that contains several enums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newest versions of Matlab you can:

```
   classdef WeekDays
       enumeration
            Sunday,Monday %You fill the rest yourself :)
       end
   end
```

Then, access it from another file like that:

```
  WeekDays.Sunday;
```

- It is an `.m` code, pure Matlab. You need to have Matlab version 2011a or higher.
- You don't need a type for the enums, unlike Java, Matlab is a dynamic language.

Comment: this is m code? classdef is class? is it a mix od 2 languages ?

Comment: Andrey, how do I specify text ,is it like java ? COLOR('Red'),...?

Comment: and  from another file toto.m , how do I can access : WeekDays.COLOR ?

Comment: thnaks Andrey , but in the same file.m could I define several enums ?

Comment: No, the class is the enum.